# Microsoft OA | Longest Substring Without 3 Contiguous Occurrences of Letter

Tags: javascript, strings, interview-questions, ecmascript-6, iteration

For the following question, does my JS Solution seem correct?

I'm looking for some peer review.

> Q: Given a string s containing only a and b, find longest substring of s such that s does not contain more than two contiguous occurrences of a and b.

Examples: 
"aabbaaaaabb" => "aabbaa" 
"aabbaabbaabbaa" => "aabbaabbaabbaa"

```
function maxLenSubStr(s) {
    let start = 0, end = 0;
    let numOfConsecutiveChars = 0;
    let res = "";
    while (end <= s.length) {
        numOfConsecutiveChars++;
        if (numOfConsecutiveChars > 2 || end == s.length) { // time to end our substring is these two cases
            if (end-start > res.length) res = s.substring(start,end); // if it is not longer, there is no need to store it
            start = end-1; // slide our window so we can look for a new valid substring
            numOfConsecutiveChars--; // now we have a valid substring with two contiguous occurrences instead of three
        }
        if (s[end] !== s[end+1]) numOfConsecutiveChars = 0;
        end++;
    }
    return res;
    // Time Complexity: O(n)
    // Space Complexity: O(1)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After some tests, the code does look correct, but the logic takes *some time* to parse and understand, which is a significant disadvantage; when writing good, maintainable code, readability is usually the most important factor to consider.

If a script is running too slowly for your liking, you can run a performance test to identify the bottleneck(s) and then fix those bottlenecks (possibly with hard-to-read code like this), but before then, better to write easy-to-write, easy-to-understand code first.

If it were me, I'd use a regular expression. It'll have many fewer "moving parts" than going through the string manually and counting up lengths, and REs are quite widely used for general string matching and manipulation across most programming languages; it's something a programmer will probably already be familiar with, so hopefully using them won't present a problem.

The one complication with a regular expression is that when there may be overlapping matches, the code can get somewhat ugly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20833295) for examples. Here, with a string of `abbba`, you'd have to consider both `abb` and `bba`, where the middle `b` is contained in both. Rather than deal with overlapping matches, I'll replace all 3+-contiguous-occurrences with 4-contiguous-occurrences beforehand. Then it's trivial to use `.split` to split along the middle of each 4-contiguous section, and then return the longest string in the resulting array:

```js
const maxLenSubStr = s => s
  // Expand 3 or more contiguous occurrences to 4 contiguous occurrences
  // eg 'abbba' -> 'abbbba'
  .replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g, '$&$1')
  // Split along the middle of each 4-contiguous subsequence
  // eg 'abbbba' -> ['abb', 'bba']
  .split(/(?<=\1(.))(?=\1{2})/)
  .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);

console.log(maxLenSubStr("aabbaaaaabb")); //  => "aabbaa"
console.log(maxLenSubStr("aabbaabbaabbaa")); //  => "aabbaabbaabbaa"
console.log(maxLenSubStr("baaa")); //  => "baa"
```

For the regular expressions, the same technique is being used in both. Capture a character in a group, then backreference that group to match the same character again as many times as needed.

- `(.)\1{2,}` - `(.)` captures the character, `\1{2,}` matches it again 2 or more times, then replaces with 4 occurrences of the character.
- `(?<=\1(.))(?=\1{2})` - `(.)` captures the character in the lookbehind, [preceded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36047988) by `\1`, another occurrence of the character. Then `(?=\1{2})` looks ahead for 2 more occurrences of the character.

I'd consider this an order of magnitude easier to understand than your original code. It's much easier to see at a glance that it'll carry out the desired logic properly, at least for those with a bit of experience with regular expressions. Whether it's worth replacing your original code with it would depend on you and your team's familiarity with REs.

If you had to do it without lookbehind (which is not supported on out-of-date browsers), then split with another capturing group around the whole left match, or use `.match` instead, to match characters until encountering 3 in a row:

```js
const maxLenSubStr = s => s
  // Expand 3 or more contiguous occurrences to 4 contiguous occurrences
  // eg 'abbba' -> 'abbbba'
  .replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g, '$&$1')
  // Split along the middle of each 4-contiguous subsequence
  // eg 'abbbba' -> ['abb', 'bba']
  // Lazily match characters until encountering the end of the string
  // or until 3 of the same character are in a row
  .match(/.*?(?:$|(.)\1(?=\1))/g)
  .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);

console.log(maxLenSubStr("aabbaaaaabb")); //  => "aabbaa"
console.log(maxLenSubStr("aabbaabbaabbaa")); //  => "aabbaabbaabbaa"
console.log(maxLenSubStr("baaa")); //  => "baa"
console.log(maxLenSubStr("aaab")); //  => "aab"
```

If you were to keep using your original code, I'd suggest:

- Use strict comparison `===` instead of sloppy comparison `==` (which has [weird coercion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) a reader of the code shouldn't have to worry about)
- Use spaces between non-unary operators and operands, for readability, eg `end - start > res.length` instead of `end-start > res.length`
- Rather than `numOfConsecutiveChars--;`, since the new consecutive count will always be 2, better to assign 2 to it directly: `numOfConsecutiveChars = 2`
- Increment `numOfConsecutiveChars` only when a subsequent consecutive character is found, and not unconditionally. (Your current logic works, it's just confusing)

Answer (score 2):

If I saw this code in an interview I would want to look at multiple factors, including:

- how well the code works
- how readable the code is

Obviously the code works for the given input. In terms of readability it seems the code has consistent indentation, though some of the lines are quite long and I have to scroll horizontally to read the entire contents.

While it isn't wrong to use a `while` loop, it could be re-written using a `for` loop, since a `for` loop is a `while` loop with the initialization, condition and final-expression expressions contained in one line (though it could span multiple lines if necessary).

```
for (let start = 0, end = 0, numOfConsecutiveChars = 0; end <= s.length; end++) {
```

This will eliminate the need to have `end++` at the end of the loop block, and keep the iterator variables scoped to the block instead of the entire function.

This line

> ```
> numOfConsecutiveChars++;
> ```

could be removed if the conditional line that follows it is updated to include the increment in a [pre-fix manner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#Prefix_increment):

```
if (++numOfConsecutiveChars > 2 || end == s.length) {
```

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Complexity and performance review

### JavaScript does not like strings.

It is always best to avoid direct string manipulation in JavaScript when compared to manipulating numbers.

As the function involves stepping over each character you can get a lot of performance by converting characters to numbers using `String.charCodeAt`.

Not all JavaScript numbers are equally as performant. Internally JavaScript has several different types of `Number` (depending on which JS engine is used). The simplest internal number type is 32bit Signed Integer  (uint32) which CPUs can handle quicker than Doubles (64 bit floating point).

You can force a number to be uint32 by performing a bit-wise operation on it. Thus `String.charCodeAt(index) | 0` will give you the most performant data from a string.

### Complexity

You have commented in your code

```
// Space Complexity: O(1)
// Time Complexity: O(n)
```

#### Space

Your function is at least \$O(n)\$ space if we ignore how the heap works and \$O(n*log(n))\$ if we dont.

The function returns a string, javascript does not use references for strings, it copies every character every time you move it. So a simple function

```
function giveBackStr(str) { return str }
const a = giveBackStr("1234567890");
```

has a space complexity of \$O(n)\$ as the string is first copied to argument `str` and then if return is assigned a second copy is created. So the above example will need RAM for 20 characters.

If we don't ignore the way the JS heap works the space complexity gets worse as RAM assigned inside a function is not removed from the heap until all code has finished executing. Thus as with time complexity your length check is causing the function to use too much RAM (see next section)

#### Time

The way you track the max length of the found string means that the time complexity is greater that \$O(n)\$

```
if (end-start > res.length) res = s.substring(start,end)
```

The best case for your code is \$O(n)\$ however the worst is \$O(n.log(n))\$

For example the string `"ababab"`. Each iteration will get a longer string to return. Thus you will need to create `"a"`, then `"ab"`, `"aba"`, `"abab"`, ... to `"ababab"`.

JaveScript copies strings one character at a time. So for the 6 characters `"ababab"` just to copy parts of the string 6 times requires the movement of 20 characters, meaning time complexity worst case is \$O(n.log(n))\$

### Rewrite

The next snippet is written to have

- a time complexity of \$O(n)\$ which can not be improved,
- a space complexity of \$O(n)\$ as the argument and returns are strings this can not be improved.
- and to be performant within the constraints of the above two points.

Code

```
function maxLenSubStrB(str) {
    var i = 0, max = 0, from = 2, start, c1, c2;
    const nextChar = () => str.charCodeAt(i++) | 0;
    const checkMax = () => {
        const len = i - from;
        if (len > max) {
            start = from - 2;
            max = len;
        }
        from = i;
    }
    if (str.length > 2) {             
        c1 = nextChar();
        c2 = nextChar();            
        while (i < str.length) {
            const c = nextChar();
            c2 === c && c2 === c1 && checkMax();
            c1 = c2;
            c2 = c;
        }
        i ++;
        checkMax();
        return str.slice(start, start + max + 1);
    }
    return str;  
}
```

This is may not be the most performant way.

- there can be an early exit by checking if the number of remain characters is less than max
- Using `String.indexOf` to locate triples

However the gains would be small

### Note on Strings and Number

To point out how bad JavaScript is at manipulating strings if we change the function `nextChar` from

```
const nextChar = () => str.charCodeAt(i++) | 0;
```

to

```
const nextChar = () => str[i++];
```

it takes twice as long to find a solution.

Removing the bit-wise conversion to Uint32

```
const nextChar = () => str.charCodeAt(i++);
```

results in a small 4-5% slowdown.

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks.